# Replacing samba.schema (LDAP) on Mavericks Server

Tags: macos, server.app, smb, open-directory, ldap

I have a Mavericks Server with Open Directory, where all my user information is stored.

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server which has hitherto served up files using NFS. My Mavericks desktop is having difficulty with NFS, so - given that Apple is dropping support for NFS - it seems to be the time to move to Samba. So, I'm trying to replace NFS with a Samba server on Ubuntu 14.04.

When logging into the Samba server I would like to use the same usernames and passwords  as I use everywhere else. This means that the Samba server has to talk to LDAP on the Mavericks server, which is per se no problem.

However, Samba needs its own schema to be installed in LDAP. In Mavericks Server Apple has installed its own version of the Samba LDAP schema. The Apple Samba schema is not a subset of the Samba schema that I need to install.

Presumably there is a reason for this. Can anyone tell me what I lose if I nuke the Apple LDAP schema in Mavericks Server and replace it with the current Samba schema from samba.org?

Steve

Comment: I've found an article that looks that it might help with this problem: [link](http://aarononeal.info/configure-freenas-samba-for-os-x-server-open-directory/). I'll look at it and report back after I've tried it out.

Comment: Should anyone be following this: BEWARE. My first attempt at modifying the LDAP schema for Samba in my OD resulted in network logins becoming impossible. To be specific: users could no longer login to radius or e-mail.

Comment: I've given up on Samba. Yosemite seems to run better with NFS (at least with the apps I had problems with), so I'll stick with NFS for the time being.